# polynomial with real coeficients for a matrix

Tags: matrices

let $A$ belongs to $M_{n \times n}$ then we have to show that there exist a polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients such that $f(A)=0$..we know that this is true for characteristic polynomial i.e for every  matrix  satisfies its characteristic polynomial i mean $f(A)=0$ (by a famous hamilton's theorem..its look like characteristic polynomial is not requirement here due to this reason i really cant understand what the question is??

Comment: Maybe the question preceds Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: sory i couidn't got it??

Comment: If you're following a textbook,maybe that problem is supposed to be solved before you learn about  Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: nup in text book this problem is asked after cayley hamilton

Comment: Is $A$ a real matrix?

Comment: i think it is..cz polynomial is restricted with real coefficients

Comment: I can only think that maybe they want to take $A\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ and want you to find a real polynomial which annihilates $A$. This isn't simply Cayley-Hamilton.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st $n^2+1$ powers of $A$  live in an $n^2$ dimensional space, hence are linearly dependent.